# load dialog pre load page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i use dialog box without dialog ui for show erorr event in web page

```
<div id="downloadcredit" style="width:100%;position:fixed;height:100%;min-height:overflow:hidden;background-color:rgba(127,127,127,0.4);display:none;" >
<div style="text-align:right;width:466px;position:absolute;left:0;right:0;height:337px;min-height:overflow:hidden;background:url(images/creditbase.png);color:black;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;top:200px;font:16px behzad;">
<div style="width:100%;height:40px;background:transparent;font:20px behzad;padding-top:8px;color:#818181;text-align:center;"><span style="float:right;font:12px tahoma;font-weight:bold;color:#75797A;margin-right:15px;cursor:pointer;margin-top:6px;" onclick="$('#downloadcredit').slideUp('slow');">X</span></div>
<div style="margin:175px auto 10px;width:95%;font:11px tahoma;text-align:center;color:white;line-height:165%;">

<p> Erorr Sample ...
</div>
</div>
</div>
<body onload="$('#downloadcredit').slideDown('1000');">
```

but my page is Slow loading and 3 or 4 second after page complete loaded dialog show :( .
any way for show dialog first and page load in background?

Comment: Could you please put the code on http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

I usualy apply the style "display:none" to the target container, then you can use the .load() function and use the callback to show your container filled with data.

Basically :

```
$('#target').hide();
$('#target').addClass("loading-layer");
$('#target').load('toto.php',function(){
    $('#target').removeClass("loading-layer");
    $('#target').show();
});
```

Comment: l dont know how l can use this code . please give me sample .